# What is the canonical way to reference a git repository and branch

Tags: git

I think I saw somewhere that `repository#branch` was legit, but not sure.  Have done a bit of searching for this, it's one of those things that's a little hard to find good search keywords for.  "git repository branch canonical" hasn't returned much.

The reason I ask is just simply to know the best way to refer to repository branches amongst my development team.  It's kind of a trivial question, I know, but I'm just curious about it.  I regularly work with several repositories and several branches within each so it's something that I need to use a lot.

Comment: Can you give more context about the problem you're trying to solve? This isn't clear.

Comment: @Daenyth, Sorry about that, you're right, shouldn't have been so brief.  Updated.  It's kind of an oddly trivial question, I know - thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a repository by name a standard convention is to just say "name dot git" or to write "name.git". For example, if I want to refer to git's own repo I say "git.git".

As for referring to a branch, I've never seen a situation where someone needs a shorthand to refer to a particular branch on a particular repo. I'm not saying the need doesn't exist, but I've never come across it. If I had to tell someone that I'd just say "the 'next' branch on git.git". If you do find you need to use a shorthand frequently, you should just make up whatever you want and then teach your coworkers the same shorthand. "git.git#next" seems like a reasonable solution to me.

Comment: Thanks @kevin, sounds reasonable.  Ya basically after having to refer to a particular branch on a particular repo about the 50th time I wanted a shorthand for it :)  Maybe the root problem is that we're using too many repos at once here.